# Web applications and multi-threading

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading, web-applications

I'm working on porting a desktop application (WinForm) to a web application (Java/Spring/JPA). The problems are many and I'm struggling a bit...

Now the problem is threading!

In the original application, that performs the export of certain data from the DB, there is a progress-bar indicating the progress of the process.

I want to port this progress-bar in the new web application. To do this I thought of using AJAX and use a separate thread to run the data export.

The main concerns are:

- Am I following the right approach? Are there problems using multi-threading in web applications?
- If during the export process F5 or refresh button are pressed what exactly happens? How can I stop the process?
- How do I update the progress bar periodically? Do I have to make calls via ajax to the server?

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?26661-quot-progress-bar-quot-in-Spring-web-app) and tried the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find my answers Inline

**I am following the right approach? Are there problem in using multi-threading in web applications**?

-Yes you are on correct path. No there is no such problem in multi-threading in web application and its as easy as you do it in WinForm. Instead of using Dispatcher to update the UI, you would be making AJAX calls and with javascript DOM manipulation would take place.

**If during the export process F5 or refresh button are pressed what exactly happens? How an I stop the process?**

-Unfortunately there is no easy way. The standard way is, when such kind of processing is done and the user hits F5, you would show a dialog(with help of javascript) and inform user that the job is still running. If the user still wants to refresh then you have make another request to the server for cancelling the task.(You need to store thread id or cancellation token some where to cancel the task)

**How do I update the progress bar periodically? Do I have to make calls via ajax to the server?**

-The standard way is, generally you show show a loading image. IF you want to show a context senstive progress bar, it would mean you have to do polling. Here is an example by Dino Espito. Though its in ASP.NET, you could understand the underlying principle
[Dino Espito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx)

Comment: When you say _"you would show a dialog(with help of javascript) and inform user that the job is still running"_, you mean intercept the "refresh event"?

Comment: Yes, you can easily do it by handling key press events in javascripts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm primarily an ASP.Net developer but from what I know of the HTTP protocol this just isn't the way to go about it. I've seen a lot of fairly clever solutions for this but in the end what becomes clear is that the HTTP protocol simply isn't designed to work like this.

Obviously you're aware that a flash or silverlight app would be able to do this but that comes with it's own set of issues.

Myself I prefer to keep all the weirdness on the server. In the past I've had to come up with a way to deliver several thousand emails through a web application and update the user on how it's coming along. I designed a set of tables to act as a queue. The web application would simply place any delivery requests in this queue and the progress bar would be determined by a request that checks the status of the items in the queue. Running in the background was a windows service which would also check this queue and was actually responsible for delivering the mail and setting the status of each item as it completed or failed.

It was a bit difficult to develop since windows services can be tricky but once it was up and running it was extremely smooth and reliable. Depending on your circumstances perhaps a simple scheduled task set to run every few minutes would do the trick for you.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, I could launch a thread that does the "dirty work" and then from my web page i could make timed requests to determine the progress of the export process...

Comment: I don't know what kind of webserver you're using but spawning threads inside a web app always makes me uncomfortable. For one thing in IIS if an uncaught exception is thrown inside a spawned thread it can crash the entire webserver. I'm not sure if this holds true for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily jump straight to running a separate thread explicitly for the export. While it would be ideal to do this, the capability of the web container to do this is going to be a limiting factor. Your traditional Java EE app server generally discourages spawning threads for this (though you can hook up to a thread pool for this). Some containers are great at freeing up the threads from blocking until the work is done (Karaf with Jetty and Camel, for instance) so that they can service other web requests while the export is occurring. But my guess is that you're probably okay with the "start export" thread blocking until it receives a response.

How long does this export take? A couple of seconds, or are we talking closer to minutes here? If it's shorter, I'd think that just putting a little "Waiting" icon with the little circular spinner on it (using your favorite Ajax library, whatever that is) would be sufficient.

If you really want a true status bar that periodically refreshes itself, then yes you'd have to poll for it at some frequency. Presumably that could be a simple request that would load some kind of progress for the job from a database table for that job ID.

Comment: The process can take several minutes, so I think that blocking the main thread waiting for the response could not be the right approach. I could start the process by an asynchronous request and check periodically the progress of the export process...

Comment: Even if you make an asynchronous request from the browser's perspective, the thread on the server servicing that request is going to be blocking in the background. At such time it won't be able to service other HTTP requests. If you are okay with this, that's the simplest approach, but if you'd like to free that up, that's when you should involve a thread pool and delegate to a Runnable via an Executor.